# Adding flow arrows for the solution of an ODE

Tags: plot, matlab-figure, figure, differential-equations

I have on ODE of the form $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ that I managed to plot its solution in Matlab.
I want to add "direction of progress arrows" to the curves.
The curves illustrated below are the paramteric plot of x(t) and y(t), each having 1500 steps.
[image]
The black arrow seen on left has been inserted using the "Insert Arrow" option from the figure's window.
I want to add arrows like those in the black and white picture attached.
[image]
Is there any way to do it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever figured this out, however, one solution, though not elegant, could be to use the [Plot with Direction Function](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1676-plot-with-direction) from the MATLAB FEx.

After computing your ODE solution, you could take various points and use the above Plot with Direction function from the FEx. Below is some pseudo code which describes what I am talking about.

```
    [x_sol, y_sol] = ODE_METHOD(@fcn,...);
    x_Points4Arrow = x_sol([...]);
    y_Points4Arrow = 

    % Plot ODE solution 
    for ind = 1:numel(y_Points4Arrow)
    |    hold on
    |    Plot With Direction(x_Points4Arrow(ind), y_Points4Arrow(ind));
    |    hold off
    end   
    % Modify axes and anything else
```

You could even modify that function to take in the Line Properties - or just modify the code if you only want one color.